# Send a downlink message to TTN via thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard, lorawan

I have integrated thingsboard and ttn to view uplink messages and creating dashboards. I'm interested in sending downlink messages as well. The examples I read ,take input from the uplink and add it as a payload field to the downlink and trigger the message by some change in attributes.
I want to send a custom payload (6 bytes) every hour and also change it based on user input.
Any help is appreciated.
Sorry for silly questions, newbie here...

Cheers

Comment: Are you using Thingsboard PE or CE?

Comment: I m using the trial version of Thingsboard Professional Edition

Comment: Have similar question. Using Ubunut 20.04, ThingsBoard CE, v.3.3.2. After receiving the payload from gateway to the Thingsboard, want to send ack message back to the gateway. The particular message is 2-byte hex string. That will confirm that the message has been successfully received. This GW's specification is made that way actually.